# Start programs with a filename in all subfolders BATCH script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to code a script that have to START all programs with a specific filename in their own working directory.
The problem born when I try to extract the working directory from the filename path.
In my example in the for loop I'll try to print the working directory removing the first 15 characters from right (estrattore.exe lenght)

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set a=%%p

for /R "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\----\UP --\---" %%p in (estrattore.exe) do  (
    if exist "%%p" echo %a:~0,-15%
)

pause
```

Comment: see `for /?` for modifiers: use `%%~fp` for full qualified file name. Use `%%~dpp` for drive/path only.

Comment: `set a =%%p` does not make any sense, as `%%p isn't defined at that point. So `%a:~0,-15%` also can't work at all.  (but nice try...)

Comment: I've tried to print the output in the loop. The p variable is rightly defined. Infact the output will be different for any loop if I print the %%p.

I'm looking for your first comment

Comment: if a=`%%p`, then `%a:~0,-15` is (literal) `%%p` minus the last 15 chars. As there are only three chars (two percent signs and a p), `%a:~0,-15%` is empty, So `echo %a:~0-15%` is the same as just `echo  `, which  gives you `Echo is Off`

Answer (score 0):

You have used `@echo OFF` which disable Echo

Use `@echo on` to start echo

Comment: This is not the problem, infact if I write: 'echo %%p'  the output will be right, not ECHO DISABLED.

Comment: @RaffaellaCaragallo lemme check and get back

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the FOR loop structure.

I've removed the `(` and `)` after the `do` command.

I've edited my script as well:

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\-----\-- --\" %%p in (----.exe) do   if exist "%%p" START "%%p" /D "%%~dpp" "%%p"
pause
```

It will start the program, with the specified working dir and title.